# Reversing Sencha Touch 2 Scrollbar

Tags: extjs

I am implementing a sencha touch app on the desktop and I am looking to “reverse” the direction of the scrollbar. Has anyone implemented this?

Comment: Is this Sencha Touch or ExtJS Modern?

Comment: This is Sencha Touch

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box solution.

***How to start***

You can take a look at

```
// panel p is the scrollable panel
const scrollbar = p.getScrollable().getIndicators().y.barElement

scrollbar.dom.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)"
```

You will have to set the transform origin, but this should help you jumpstart the problem.